# What is the full syntax structure for private set in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I use *Code A* as shown below frequently.

Unfortunately, I can't understand the syntax structure for `private set` completely, so I get the following error when I replace *Code A* with *Code B*.

> Function invocation 'set(...)' expected

What is the full syntax structure for `private set` in Kotlin?

#### Code A

```
var isRecording by mutableStateOf(false)
               private set
```

#### Code B

```
var isRecording by mutableStateOf(false)  private set
```

Comment: See [Kotlin Documentation, Concepts, Classes and Objects, Properties, Getters and Setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters). The linebreak seems to be part of the syntax.

Comment: If you want to have a one-liner, you need to add a `;` after `mutableStateOf(false)`... The grammar doesn't show anything about the new line (or I didn't look at the right place), but about the semi-colon... ( https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#propertyDeclaration ) ...

Comment: @Roland it does mention on that page: "Also for better readability some simplifications are made: (...) new line tokens are excluded".

Comment: @Roland wouldn't it be `(NL+ | SEMICOLON)` then instead of `(NL+ SEMICOLON)?`. I don't really have experience in this grammar notation but that's what I would think when I read that. I would think the `?` at the end makes it optional, and the lack of `|` to mean that it's "one or more new lines followed by a semicolon"

Comment: twice thanks ;-) wanted to correct it as I read it again... but then... meetings ;-) so the following link may be more appropriate to answer the question: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/release/grammar/src/main/antlr/KotlinParser.g4#L185 ...  however I still not see why the new line is not required, if a semi-colon is put there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant grammar, from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html :

```
propertyDeclaration (used by declaration)
  : modifiers? ('val' | 'var') typeParameters?
    (receiverType '.')?
    (multiVariableDeclaration | variableDeclaration)
    typeConstraints?
    (('=' expression) | propertyDelegate)? ';'?
    ((getter? (semi? setter)?) | (setter? (semi? getter)?))
  ;
propertyDelegate (used by propertyDeclaration)
  : 'by' expression
  ;
```

My take on it is that the new line is needed because otherwise it assumes the `private set` is part of the `expression` in the `propertyDelegate`.

And indeed, it is actually possible to write a functional one-liner where the `private set` is part of the expression. this is correct functional code:

```
val set = 0

var isRecording by mutableStateOf(false) private set

public infix fun <A, B> A.private(that: B): A = this
```

But I would highly recommend to never write such code haha.

Comment: but the simplified grammar does not mention the required new-line... and the parser instead, as you also already saw, mentions `NL+ SEMICOLON`, which doesn't really match what I could achieve, i.e. `var x by mutableStateOf(false); private set`... and I would rather remove the lower part from the answer... or put the disclaimer in front and ENLARGED ;o) aaaaah... such code should better not be shared... :-)

Comment: @Roland what you could achieve I think is covered by the `(getter? (NL* semi? setter)?` part. the `semi` there is your semicolon. But yeah, the `(NL+ SEMICOLON)?` part is puzzling. The way I understand it it should make it possible to write `;;private set` on a new line, one semicolon from the SEMICOLON and one from the `semi` but it doesn't allow that. Strange..

Comment: ah... I see... yes, then semicolon is clear... but I also would have thought that `\n;;private set` should work ...